# How to write JUnit test with hardcoded object possesing LocalDate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

When I'm trying to test my Api Controller with hardcoded Object everything is fine unitil I try to add LocalDate parameter to Object.

My Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ApiTransitController.class)
public class ApiTransitControllerTest {


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private TestService testService;

    @MockBean
    private ReportsService reportsService;

    @MockBean
    private TransitService transitService;

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateTransit() throws Exception {

        Transit transit = new Transit("London", "Paris", 12L, 
    LocalDate.of(2018,10,12));

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String transitJsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(transit);


        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/transit")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(transitJsonString))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());

        verify(transitService).addTransit(eq(new Transit("London", "Paris", 12L, 
   LocalDate.of(2018,10,12))));
    }
}
```

Model:

@Entity
public class Transit {

```
@Column(name = "id")
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String sourceAdress;
private String destinationAdress;
private Long price;
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
private LocalDate date;
@JsonSerialize(using=DistanceSerializer.class)
private Long distance;

 public Transit(String sourceAdress, String destinationAdress, Long price, LocalDate date) {
        this.sourceAdress = sourceAdress;
        this.destinationAdress = destinationAdress;
        this.price = price;
        this.date = date;
    }

//getters and setters, equals and hashCode and toString
```

Api Controller:

```
 @PostMapping("/api/transit")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createTransit(@RequestBody Transit transit){
        LOG.info("Saving transit={}", transit);
        transitService.addTransit(transit);
    }
```

I tried adding DateTimeFormmater and few other ways, but still I cant pass the test. Thank you for your time.

Comment: maybe `Locale.of(..)` returns a new instance, in that case the object would not be equal

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
verify(transitService).addTransit(eq(new Transit("London", "Paris", 12L, 
   LocalDate.of(2018,10,12))));
```

to this:

```
verify(transitService).addTransit(eq(transit));
```

The two objects aren't equal, also you don't need to create a new object you can use already created one.

Comment: Nothing changed, the test is not passing.

Answer (score 0):

I added JsonSerializer to date of the Model:

Model:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
@JsonSerialize(using=DateSerializerNumberTwo.class)
    private LocalDate date;
```

Serializer:

```
public class DateSerializerNumberTwo extends StdSerializer<LocalDate> {


    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public DateSerializerNumberTwo(){
        this(null);
    }
    protected DateSerializerNumberTwo(Class<LocalDate> t){
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(formatter.format(value));
    }
}
```

And the test passes without any changes in the test code. I think it's beacuse the Json default response of date is  "yyyy, mm,  dd", not like Local date (yyyy-mm-dd)".